# How do you programatically position an object in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, absolute-value

In Flash this question is answered really easy because you can set the X and Y coordinates of an object:

```
newxpos = object._x;
newypos = object._y;
```

How do you do the same in Silverlight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Place the object inside a canvas element and then use:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(object, value);
Canvas.SetTop(object, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Canvas works if you want fixed positions. If you want relative positions or positions that are controlled in a more dynamic manner, you want to look into putting your controls inside a **StackPanel** or a **FlowPanel** or a **WrapPanel**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas.SetLeft(object, value);
is a good feature but if you control changes ownership dynamically it's better to target the control itself with "yourcontrolname".SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, value);